# Allow partial type

Tags: redux, flowtype

Using Flowtype together with Redux, I have a type like this:

```
export type MapState = {
  addresses: Address[],
  selected: Array<number>
}
```

and an action creator:

```
export const setParams = (params: any): Action => {
    return { type: actionTypes.SET_PARAMS, payload: { params };

}
```

In the reducer, I merge the params into the state:

```
export default (state: MapState = initialState, action: SetParamsAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_PARAMS: {
      return {
         ...state,
         ...action.payload.params
      }
 [...]
```

I'm looking for a possibility to tell Flowtype to accept `params` in the action creator, if it is an object consisting only of properties of `MapState`, so that I can get rid of the `any` in `setParams`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a [exact `PossibleParams` Object type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types) like so:

```js
type PossibleParams = {|
  addresses?: Address[],
  selected?: number[],
|};

export const setParams = (params: PossibleParams): Action => ({
  type: actionTypes.SET_PARAMS,
  payload: {
    params,
  },
});
```

You can check all the possibilities on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#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-c8vRw4WMjCZjOV0xN427Pd80wYM5MfmBlgn3QWHXQc5mywsynWOGUlpWk4HU7XixMs+W6Oo2-mAymi-NS+wFvDLLhrOU6o5XO5PGAygu-AFMPONEPtNWg5MNjHZOXd1WR4W6IfVMfJ2UY1xW5X913r5sTwsAIyCMAAJh-ADMZ5AA)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Yes, I'm aware of that possibility, but I'd rather not duplicate the type with optional attributes.

Comment: @schneck An exact Object type the only way to be 100% sure that the params can only be the specified ones and no other ones. Since all params are optional, you need to make them optional in the exact Object type. There's no other way to let `flow` check the params.